# how to find total sum of the same products from two different tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Got 2 tables - baskets of products:
basket_a

```
 a | fruit_a  | number_a 
---+----------+----------
 3 | Banana   |        0
 4 | Cucumber |        0
 1 | Apple    |       50
 2 | Orange   |       45
```

basket_b

```
 b |  fruit_b   | number_b 
---+------------+----------
 3 | Watermelon |        0
 4 | Pear       |        0
 1 | Orange     |        5
 2 | Apple      |       30
```

I need to find total amount of the fruits which match in both tables:

```
 fruit   | number 
---+----------------
 Orange  |    80
 Apple   |    55
```

I tried inner join

select a.fruit_a, a.number_a, b.fruit_b, b.number_b from basket_a as a inner join basket_b as b on a.fruit_a=b.fruit_b;

```
 fruit_a | number_a | fruit_b | number_b 
---------+----------+---------+----------
 Apple   |       50 | Apple   |       30
 Orange  |       45 | Orange  |        5
```

and i tried union:
select * from basket_a union select * from basket_b;

```
 a |  fruit_a   | number_a 
---+------------+----------
 1 | Orange     |        5
 2 | Apple      |       30
 4 | Pear       |        0
 3 | Watermelon |        0
 4 | Cucumber   |        0
 2 | Orange     |       45
 1 | Apple      |       50
 3 | Banana     |        0
```

But I couldn't group it somehow

select foo.fruit_a, foo.number_a from (select * from basket_a union select * from basket_b) as foo group by foo.fruit_a;

```
ERROR:  column "foo.number_a" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select foo.fruit_a, foo.number_a from (select * from basket_...
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the attempt you did using the inner join?

Comment: select a.fruit_a, a.number_a, b.fruit_b, b.number_b from basket_a as a inner join basket_b as b on a.fruit_a=b.fruit_b;

Comment: In your expected result, Orange should be 50 and NOT 80, right?

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables? Strange design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where doing something like:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM basket_a
INNER JOIN basket_b ON basket_a.fruit_a = basketb_fruitb;
```

To get 2, and not 4 columns do:

```
SELECT 
    basket_a.fruit_a, 
    basket_a.number_a + basket_b.number_b as number
FROM basket_a
INNER JOIN basket_b ON basket_a.fruit_a = basketb_fruitb;
```

Another way, without inner join, is:

```
SELECT
   fruit_a,
   sum(number_a)
FROM (
      SELECT fruit_a, number_a FROM basket_a
      UNION ALL
      SELECT fruit_b, number_b FROM basket_b 
     )x
GROUP BY fruit_a;
```